# Clone image as thumbnail in Dropzone JS

Tags: javascript, image, dropzone.js, file-handling

I'm using Dropzone JS to upload images and want to begin uploading a small thumbnail copy of each along with the file.  I see that Dropzone allows createImageThumbnails, but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to use that image as one to actually upload instead of just display?

Comment: Show us the code you currently have

Comment: diffidently you can is the answer, share the code once you have written it.